# What does "M O" in the Razzle Dazzle cheer song mean?

Tags: song-lyrics, oral-tradition

I would like to know what a particular line in the following cheer poem is a reference to.

> #### Razzle Dazzle
>
> **Leader**: My name is *(your name)*
>   I'm number one
>   My reputation has just begun
>   So if you see me
>   Step aside
>   Cause I ain't got the time
>
> **Response**: Ooh! She thinks she's bad!
>
> **Leader**: Shut up girls, don't make me mad!
>
> **Response**: Ooh! She thinks she's cool!
>
> **Leader**: Cool enough for all these fools!
>
> **Response**: Ooh! She thinks she's fine!
>
> **Everyone**: Fine enough to M O
>   Fine enough to macho
>   Fine enough to hula hoop
>   Fine enough for all yall fools!
>
> Razzle Dazzle *(3 claps)*
>   Razzle Dazzle *(3 claps)*

The line I particularly do not understand is "Fine enough to M O" and "Fine enough to macho."
This cheer poem is extremely common in summer camps and I've heard it so many times, but no one seems to know what "M O" is.

Comment: @Standback - I refer you to the [song-lyrics] tag. This appears to be on topic.

Comment: @Mithrandir There's still a difference between lyrics that were written by an individual, and accurately recorded, vs. asking about a literal word definition in camp cheer, which might have had any number of iterations and variations.

Comment: Which country is this from?

Comment: @Standback Just because texts have gone through change doesn't warrant that it's not worthy of clarification. So I don't see the point you're getting at. Many ancient texts have gone through variations and the newest versions are still undergoing research and clarifications.

Comment: http://campkesem.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Camp-Kesem-Stony-Brook-Winter-Newsletter1.pdf - This version is "*Fine enough to **mambo***"

Comment: OMG! I'm a camp kesem counselor! That's where I heard this song!